# Link is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My html code is

```
<div id="starimg">
  <a href="#" class="imgstar" onclick="ratingFunc()"><img src="images/star1.png" class="star" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="imgstar" onclick="ratingFunc()"><img src="images/star1.png" class="star" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="imgstar" onclick="ratingFunc()"><img src="images/star1.png" class="star"/></a>
  <a href="#" class="imgdarkstar" onclick="ratingApp()"><img src="images/star2.png" class="star1"/></a>
  <a href="#" class="imgdarkstar" onclick="ratingApp()"><img src="images/star2.png" class="star1" /</a>  
</div>
```

my java script code is

```
function ratingFunc(){
    if( $('.star').attr("src")=='images/star1.png'){
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='images/star2.png' class="star1"/>");
        starcheck=true;
    }
    else{
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='images/star1.png' class="star"/>");
        starcheck=false;
    }
}

function ratingApp(){
    if($('.star1').attr("src")=='images/star2.png'){
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='images/star1.png' class="star"/>");
        starcheck=true;
    }
    else{
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='images/star2.png' class"star1"/>");
        starcheck=false;
    }
}
```

when i am clicking on image then these function are not working..please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(this)` here isn't making much sense, are you refering to function itself? use something like `$('a.star')` instead.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't know what does this `$(this)` mean within.
It does, but thats not what you are looking for :)

Replace `$(this)` with `$(".star")` in first function and
Replace `$(this)` with `$(".star1")` in other function.

and it will work fine.

Comment: this means i am selecting which link and i am replacing one imag to another when i am clicking on link.i only want to know how to call the function while clicking on link.

Comment: ok i just wanted to know this.not any other thing..thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

What is the use of `starcheck` variable?

I can see that your links have two classes at the same time : I'm not sure that's helping. You should separate your classnames with single spaces in order to use more than one class for a single element :

```
<a href="#" class="imgstar star" onclick="ratingFunc()"><img src="images/star1.png"/></a>
```

For more info, [check W3C HTML standards](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp).

Comment: However, `class="star"` is a property of the `img` tag, rather than the `a` tag.

Comment: actualy i want to change image on clicking on the link thats why i have taken two classes.i am using this to show that i am selecting particular image and i want to call the function on clicking on particuar link.but when i am clicking on link function is not calling.i want to know how to call the function on clicking on link so that it can work.

Comment: yes star is the property of img tag and img star is the property of link